# Dynamically add an escape backslash to backslash in a regex-to-be string in javascript

Tags: javascript

*Purpose:*
Test input against a **custom string turned regex** (the initial regex-to-be string varies).

*Problem:*
Add escape slashes **dynamically** to every backslash in a string-to-be-regex.
This is the **???** part in the below code but this can be in a different (fairly succint) way if needed.

So **how to turn**
`var initial = "^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]){2,}$";`
into
`var pattern = "^[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)*@([\\w-]+\\.)+([a-zA-Z]){2,}$";)`
(so it will work on different regex-strings too)
?

*Code:*

```
var initial = "^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]){2,}$";      

??? (needs to result in 'pattern' variable with double slashes as above)

pattern = new RegExp(pattern);    
var result = pattern.test("some@mail.com");
```

I can't figure it out. I tried `split` with `join`, `replace`, `stringify` and `String.raw` but none of them seemed to work (often just removing the initial backslash/returning the array as a single item).

I also looked at the various backslash adding questions but nothing really seemed to work. Is this even possible in a succint way?

Comment: I would suggest that you start by logging `initial` to console ... you’ll notice something lacking there already.

Comment: Hmm.. thank you. So I assume that the escape slashes have to be added right into the initial string?

Comment: Slashes that aren’t there in the first place, can not be replaced with anything else. If you want to write this as _code_, then you have to have the double backslashes right there, `var initial = "^[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]...`, so that in the actual _value_ you get your single backslashes to begin with. If the data is eventually supposed to come from somewhere else (like user input read from a form field), the situation is different - if the user inputs `foo\bar` into an input field and you read the value from there, then the backslash is already in there.

Comment: Well obviously not (I did notice the missing slashes on log) :)
I suppose they need to be added right as double slashes then (not user input but more like a plugin input by a developer). Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Using `String.raw` and `replace` method

```js
var initial = String.raw`^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]){2,}$`;
var pattern = initial.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
console.log(pattern);
```

Comment: Hmm, yes, I tried that before and it does work in this form, but unfortunately the string differs every time and needs to be linked in as a variable as in `String.raw`${initial}`` but in this form it no longer works (apparently the unescaped slashes are already evaluated and removed by then). But ty!